# Remove minimise and maximise Button

Tags: python, tkinter, window

I have problem in my Tkinter application.

The code is the following:

```
def help_stats(self):
    self.help_about = tkinter.Toplevel(relief=tkinter.GROOVE)
    self.help_about.title('Statistika')
    self.help_about.config(width="350", height="300")   
    self.help_about.resizable(width=tkinter.FALSE, height=tkinter.FALSE)
    self.help_about_label = tkinter.Label(self.help_about,
                                          text="Something")
    self.help_about_label.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, expand=1,
                               fill=tkinter.BOTH, padx=20, pady=10)
```

If I click on something in my menu, this function is called, and a new window is created. I need, from that created window, to delete minimise Button and only leave the closing button. Is that possible?

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969870/removing-minimize-maximize-buttons-in-tkinter

Comment: i was already there, i wont able to make it work, thats because i write new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `attributes` as shown below. It removes both minimize and maximize button. I have tested the code on `Windows 8`.

```
self.help_about.attributes("-toolwindow",1)
```

Modify your code as shown below:

```
def help_stats(self):
    self.help_about = tkinter.Toplevel(relief=tkinter.GROOVE)
    self.help_about.attributes("-toolwindow",1)
    self.help_about.title('Statistika')
    self.help_about.config(width="350", height="300")   
    self.help_about.resizable(width=tkinter.FALSE, height=tkinter.FALSE)
    self.help_about_label = tkinter.Label(self.help_about, text="Something")
    self.help_about_label.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, expand=1, fill=tkinter.BOTH, padx=20, pady=10)
```

Comment: well i try this too, and it give me error 
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Psychotronix\Dropbox\PROJEKT 1.py", line 76, in help_stats
    self.help_about.attribute("-toolwindow",1)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'attribute'

Comment: Which OS are you running this code on? It's working for me as expected without any error on Windows 8

Comment: you have given `attribute`. That's why it's complaining. use `attributes`. copy paste the code from the Answer otherwise

Comment: well i must have problem somewhere else, if i use it in new project it works :) thank you

Comment: does not work on ubuntu: bad attribute "-toolwindow": must be -alpha, -topmost, -zoomed, -fullscreen, or -type