# Mysterious extra space after buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm running tkinter on Python3.4 on Windows and I want two buttons in my GUI box. 
I'm following [[this link]](http://sebsauvage.net/python/gui/)

The code is this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        button_crop = tk.Button(self, text=u"Crop", command=self.OnCrop)
        button_crop.pack(side="left")

        button_reset = tk.Button(self, text=u"Reset", command=self.OnReset)
        button_reset.pack(side="left")

    def OnCrop(self):
        pass

    def OnReset(self):
        pass

app = App()

app.mainloop()
```

Now I get a button which has some extra space to the right

[image]

I've tried initialising a `grid()` and then `button_crop.grid(column=0, row=1)` but I get the same result.

Please help me remove this extra blank space to the right.

Comment: Try to remove min and max buttons. It seems that form cannot be less than size of system buttons. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969870/removing-minimize-maximize-buttons-in-tkinter

Comment: @ventik That is not desirable.. I'm ok with increasing the size of the buttons to fit the minimum width.

Comment: Do you want the buttons to grow to fill the space, or the window to shrink to remove the extra space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this behaviour?

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):        

        button_crop = tk.Button(self, text=u"Crop", command=self.OnCrop)
        button_crop.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.E, tk.W))

        button_crop = tk.Button(self, text=u"Reset", command=self.OnReset)
        button_crop.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.E, tk.W))

        for i in range(2):
            self.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def OnCrop(self):
        pass

    def OnReset(self):
        pass

app = App()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can I not just extend size of the "crop" and "reset" buttons till they both just add up to the minimum width?

Comment: Yes, this is great! Could you explain what changes in your code helped me get this behaviour? Thanks a ton.

Comment: columnconfigure sets options for some column, weight=1 means that this column will be stretchable. read more here http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid-config.html

Comment: Thanks @ventik for the help