# How to remove minimize/maximize buttons while preserving the icon?

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

Is it possible to display the icon for my `toplevel` and `root` window after removing the minimize and maximize buttons? I tried using `-toolwindow` but the icon can't be displayed afterwards. Is there another way I can remove the min and max size buttons from window while still displaying the icon?

```
from tkinter import *


def top():
    tp = Toplevel()
    tp.geometry("300x300")
    tp.attributes("-toolwindow", 1)
    tp.iconbitmap("My icon.ico")


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

b = Button(root, text="open window with icon", command=top).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "As is" it's impossible, because tool windows don't use icons. You need to play with Window Manager and [styling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx) directly, however, there's no universal solution for all systems.

Comment: @CommonSense thanks for the response i checked the styling by doing this ' tp.WS_ICONIC()' but am getting this error:     AttributeError: 'Toplevel' object has no attribute 'WS_ICONIC'

Comment: This is more complicated than you think, but I posted what I meant as an answer!

Answer (score 12):

### Windows-specific solution

First option is to make your `toplevel` window [transient](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.transient-method) for the `root` window which is a [really simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2970757/6634373) solution.
All you need to do is change line `tp.attributes("-toolwindow", 1)` to `tp.transient(root)`!

Second option is more complicated, but more universal within the Windows system.
Each window in the Windows system has it's own style, which is represented as a [logical disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) of [bit-styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx). You can build the new style from a scratch or set new style to [disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) of the old one with a bit-style (to switch it on) or to [conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) of the old one with a [negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) of bit-style (to switch it off):

- To switch off minimize/maximize:
  `new style = old style AND NOT Maximize AND NOT Minimize`
- To switch on minimize/maximize:
  `new style = old style OR Maximize OR Minimize`

For all that interaction we need the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html) library (comes with python) and a set of the WinAPI functions:

- [GetWindowLong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633585(v=vs.85).aspx) - to get a current style of the window
- [SetWindowLong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644898(v=vs.85).aspx)  - to set a new style of the window
- [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) - to update the window (note remarks section)
- [GetParent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633510(v=vs.85).aspx) - to get a hwnd of the owner window, because we're trying to make changes in the non-client area.

Check this example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes

#   shortcuts to the WinAPI functionality
set_window_pos = ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowPos
set_window_long = ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowLongPtrW
get_window_long = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowLongPtrW
get_parent = ctypes.windll.user32.GetParent

#   some of the WinAPI flags
GWL_STYLE = -16

WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 131072
WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 65536

SWP_NOZORDER = 4
SWP_NOMOVE = 2
SWP_NOSIZE = 1
SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 32


def hide_minimize_maximize(window):
    hwnd = get_parent(window.winfo_id())
    #   getting the old style
    old_style = get_window_long(hwnd, GWL_STYLE)
    #   building the new style (old style AND NOT Maximize AND NOT Minimize)
    new_style = old_style & ~ WS_MAXIMIZEBOX & ~ WS_MINIMIZEBOX
    #   setting new style
    set_window_long(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, new_style)
    #   updating non-client area
    set_window_pos(hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED)


def show_minimize_maximize(window):
    hwnd = get_parent(window.winfo_id())
    #   getting the old style
    old_style = get_window_long(hwnd, GWL_STYLE)
    #   building the new style (old style OR Maximize OR Minimize)
    new_style = old_style | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX
    #   setting new style
    set_window_long(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, new_style)
    #   updating non-client area
    set_window_pos(hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED)


def top():
    tp = tk.Toplevel()
    #   tp.geometry('300x300')
    #   tp.iconbitmap('icon.ico')

    hide_minmax = tk.Button(tp, text='hide minimize/maximize', command=lambda: hide_minimize_maximize(tp))
    hide_minmax.pack()

    show_minmax = tk.Button(tp, text='show minimize/maximize', command=lambda: show_minimize_maximize(tp))
    show_minmax.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
b = tk.Button(root, text='open window with icon', command=top)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This creates 2 windows. What if I only want one? How do I remove the minimize/maximize buttons in the main window?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and found that `root.resizable(False, False)` after `root.geometry` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", False)
```

Comment: This will prevent the window from being closed by the (X) button. That wasn't the question, though.