# How to remove/disable the minimize button in Tkinter without removing/disabling the close button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

I am building a simple login system using Tkinter in python, for that I need a non-resizable and it can be done by 'resizable(0,0) but it only disables the maximize button. But I what the minimize button to be disabled also, so please someone help me find the solution for these.

Here's the sample of my code,

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")


def signIn():

    # Opening a new window for SignIn options
    signin = Toplevel()
    signin.grab_set()
    signin.focus_set()

    # I also tried this but it removes the whole title bar along with the close 'X' button
    # root.overrideredirect(True)

# SignIn button
button = Button(root, text="Sign In", command=signIn)
button.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing minimize/maximize buttons in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969870/removing-minimize-maximize-buttons-in-tkinter)

Comment: Yes @BokiX https://stackoverflow.com/a/63359625/17518541 is the solution, but also has a new error. While using " root.attributes('-toolwindow', True) " removes the function of "signin.grab_set() and signin.focus_set()" . Is there any way to solve this with out these new errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
root.attributes('-toolwindow', True)

def signIn():

    # Opening a new window for SignIn options
    signin = Toplevel()
    signin.grab_set()
    signin.focus_set()

    # I also tried this but it removes the whole title bar along with the close 'X' button
    # root.overrideredirect(True)

# SignIn button
button = Button(root, text="Sign In", command=signIn)
button.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This solve the problem with creating another problem,  that I mentioned below the comment section of my question. So help me solve this, by the way welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the minimize and maximize use this.  It will leave you with only the x button. I gave example for only removing maximize and then one for both.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable(False, False)#removes only the maximize option

root.attributes("-toolwindow", True)#removes both the maximize and the minimize option


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yeah it works, but gives new error, that I mentioned in the previous comments